# Go build project with cmd and pkg layout - build error

Tags: go, build, standards

I'm trying to build a Go project using the layout as described in [Go Project Layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout)

I'm using go 1.9.2 on Ubuntu. My project layout is as follows

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/ayubmalik/cleanprops
    /cmd
        /cleanprops
            /main.go
    /internal
        /pkg
            /readprops.go
```

The file cmd/cleanprops/main.go is referring to the cleanprops package i.e.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ayubmalik/cleanprops"
)

func main() {
    body := cleanprops.ReadProps("/tmp/hello.props")
    fmt.Println("%s", body)
}
```

The contents of internal/pkg/readprops.go are:

```
package cleanprops

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func ReadProps(file string) string {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    return body
}
```

However when I build cmd/cleanprops/main.go, from inside directory $GOPATH/src/github.com/ayubmalik/cleanprops, using command:

```
go build cmd/cleanprops/main.go
```

I get the following error:

```
cmd/cleanprops/main.go:5:2: no Go files in /home/xyz/go/src/github.com/ayubmalik/cleanprops
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document suggests this structure:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/ayubmalik/cleanprops
    /cmd
        /cleanprops
            /main.go
    /internal
        /pkg
            /cleanprops
                /readprops.go
```

Import the package like this. The import path matches the directory structure below $GOPATH/src.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ayubmalik/cleanprops/internal/pkg/cleanprops"
)

func main() {
    body := cleanprops.ReadProps("/tmp/hello.props")
    fmt.Println("%s", body)
}
```

Comment: so there is nothing 'magic' about the 'internal/pkg' layout and it's just a convention?

Comment: There's [magic to "internal" regarding access](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit). There's no magic regarding naming. Most of what's in the document is one person's convention on how to layout a project.

Comment: The document suggests to remove src directory, but your answer includes src directory.  This is confusing.

Comment: @SreenidhiSreesha The document says that a project should not contain a `src` directory.   
 The `src` directory shown in my answer is not part of the project.  See [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) for information about this directory.